# Application created using backbone.js is not working when included in magento site

Tags: magento, backbone.js, underscore.js

Application run smoothly when it is not included in magento code.
for example _.template in underscore.js is not working in magento site also code written in backbone.js is not working when I include it in magento script.

when I remove all code written in backbone.js and write it simply using javascript and jQuery and then include it in magento-it works.

but I want to add backbone application in magento site.

Comment: Give more info on the error.